# Even numbers of \circ causes weird spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I noticed when trying to make a string of 6 `\circ` symbols that the last one is closer to the one beside it than the rest of them, after playing with it for a while it looks like an even number (greater than 2) of `\circ` causes this, how can I fix the spacing so it is even?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
1 circ: $\circ  $

2 circ: $\circ \circ $

3 circ: $\circ \circ \circ$

4 circ: $\circ \circ \circ \circ$

5 circ: $\circ \circ \circ \circ \circ $

6 circ: $\circ \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ $

7 circ: $\circ \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ $

\end{document}
```

[image: example rendered]

Comment: One way is to make `\circ` not a binary/relational operator. Use `{\circ}`

Comment: ... red circ, blue circ. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the TeXbook (page 187, solution on page 326)

> **Exercise 19.7**
>   B. L. User tried typing ‘`\eqno(*)`’ and ‘`\eqno(**)`’,
>   and he was pleased to discover that this produced the equation numbers
>   ‘(∗)’ and ‘(∗∗)’. [He had been a bit worried that they would come out
>   ‘(*)’ and ‘(**)’ instead.] But then a few months later he tried
>   ‘`\eqno(***)`’ and got a surprise. What was it?
>
> When you type an asterisk in math mode, plain TeX considers
>   `*` to be a binary operation. In the cases ‘`(*)`’ and ‘`(**)`’, the
>   binary operations are converted to type Ord, because they don't appear in
>   a binary context; but the middle asterisk in ‘`(***)`’ remains of type Bin.
>   So the result was ‘(∗ ∗ ∗)’. To avoid the extra medium spaces, you can
>   type ‘`\eqno(*{*}*)`’; or you can change `` \mathcode`* ``, if you never use
>   `*` as a binary operation.

It doesn't matter if we're in an equation number (`\eqno`); the main issue is math mode where the behavior shows. Since `\circ` is a binary operation symbol just like `*`, you get the same.

If you want evenly spaced `\circ` symbols you can use

```
{\circ}\;{\circ}\;{\circ}\;{\circ}
```

Even better, define a suitable command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\circs}{m}
 {
  \ensuremath
   {{
     {\circ}\prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 } { \; {\circ} }
   }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\circs{1}$

$\circs{2}$

$\circs{3}$

$\circs{4}$

$\circs{5}$

$\circs{6}$

$\circs{7}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great explanation (and excercise too)!

Comment: @manooooh That's due to Knuth. `;-)`

Answer (score 10):

When you issue `\show\circ` you'll see it defined as `\mathchar"220E`. The first number in this definition points to the intrinsic "format" of the character. `2` denotes a *binary operator* which has a specific spacing around. So, `\circ` is considered a binary operator and therefore expects operands on either side. Odd-numbered `\circ`s show better alignment as they supply "operands" on either side (barring accommodation for uniform spacing around consecutive `\circ`s):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

1 circ: $\circ$

2 circ: $\circ \circ$

2 circ: $\circ \circ {}$

3 circ: $\circ \circ \circ$

4 circ: $\circ \circ \circ \circ$

4 circ: $\circ \circ \circ \circ {}$

5 circ: $\circ \circ \circ \circ \circ $

6 circ: $\circ \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$

6 circ: $\circ \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ {}$

7 circ: $\circ \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$

\end{document}
```

If you just want to list a number of `\circ`s with the correct spacing, consider adding a empty math group at the end when using an even number of `\circ`s. Alternatively, use `{\circ}` or `\mathord{\circ}` to avoid the surrounding space; `\mathord` turns its argument into a math ordinal.